# How to continue a test case when an assertion failed in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, testing, casperjs, assert

Is there a way for continue a test suite when a fail occurs?
By example :

```
casper.test.begin("",3,function suite(){
  casper.start(url).then(function(){
    test.assert(...);
    test.assert(...); //If this assert fail, the script stop and the third assert isn't tested
    test.assert(...);
  }).run(function(){
    test.done();
  });
});
```

I want all assert are tested, even if some fail. Is it possible?

Comment: For unit testing this behaviour is what you would usually want. You might use "verification" approach, which checks but not stops the test execution (like suggested in the answer below). Having this situation like you describe usually signals about bad test design. Testing too much in one test. The solution would be  split it into separate tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See in [casperjs google group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/casperjs/3jlBIx96Tb8). We can surround the assert with the `casper.then(..`

This follow code works like I want (but this way isn't maybe the best?)

```
casper.test.begin("",3,function suite(){
  casper.start(url).then(function(){
    casper.then(function(){
      test.assert(...); //if fail, this suite test continue
    });
    casper.then(function(){
      test.assert(...); //so if assert(1) fail, this assert is executed
    });
    casper.then(function(){
      test.assert(...);
    });
    }).run(function(){
      test.done();
    });
});
```

Comment: For a few test this is worse than Darren's suggestion, but when you build a framework on top of CasperJS for your testing your website, this is probably a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 4):

This is normally what you want when unit testing: if it is going to fail anyway, do it quickly. I.e. fail at the first problem in each test function. Also, later tests usually assume earlier tests passed, e.g. if the page title is wrong and saying 404, there is no point testing that the correct number of images are on the page.

I am guessing you want this so that you can get more information in the test results, and one way to do that would be to use a single assert and a custom error message:

```
var title = this.getTitle();
var linkText = this.getHTML('a#testLink');
this.assert( title == "MyPage" && linkText == "continue",
  "title=" + title + ";a#testLink = " + linkText);
```

But that can get messy. If you want to use all the power of the `assert` family of functions, and not have them throw, but instead continue, a study of [the source code](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/master/modules/tester.js) shows that this might work:

```
test.assert(false, null, {doThrow:false} );
test.assertEquals(1 == 2, null, {doThrow:false} );
test.assertEquals(2 == 2);
```

And if you want this to be the default behaviour on all your asserts, well, hacking the code might be the best choice! (Change the default of `true` for `doThrow` to be `false`.)

Comment: I just find another solution =) I write this